# Просмотр поля EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, парсер

Есть поле EditText, оно служит как поле в которое вводят веб адрес, например:

> http://www.google.com

Как видите в адресе приведеном на примере, в начале есть текст: "http://", так вот, мне нужно програмно посмотреть есть ли перед адресом, который ввел пользователь, текст: "http://"....
Как это можно организовать?
можно пример кода?

Comment: Есть метод `String.startsWith(String prefix)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать класс [Uri](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html)

```
final Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://ya.ru");
uri.getScheme();
```

Метод `getScheme` для примера вернет `"http"` (или null если [схема](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#.D0.A1.D1.82.D1.80.D1.83.D0.BA.D1.82.D1.83.D1.80.D0.B0_URL) не найдена)